# Possible idea why the smileys window for forum module shows homepage?

Tags: forum

having an issue with the `{path:smileys}` tag in the submission form.html in the Forum module not showing the smileys in the popup window, but showing the entire homepage within the popup.

i've checked javascript, no issues.
site is on a subdomain (dev.domain.com) and all other forum functions work.

here is the entire link:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="window.open('{path:smileys}', '_blank', 'width=700,height=180,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,screenx=40,screeny=120,resizable=yes');">{lang:smileys}</a>
```

want to replace that above code to a lightbox, but path isn't working correctly.

not sure what could be causing this issue, so any pointers or tips will help.

thanks

Comment: Tad - it would be great if you could post the real solution you found to this problem, to help future problem solvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ended up happening is there was a 'forum' template in the main template manager and is pulling in the forum content using the {exp:forum} tag.

Nothing wrong with this, except that the forum module templates were not adjusted for this.
So in turn it was pulling in multiple sets of head and body tags.  Basically doing an iframe setup without the iframe, that helps make sense of it.

It has led me to redo the forum module templates to accommodate for the forum template in the main template manager.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, any time the home page shows instead of anything, there can be two reasons why it isn't working:

1. The content you're trying to view is secure and EE redirects to the home page.
2. The path you're trying to access throws a 404 and no 404 has been assigned.

Check the path to your smileys in the general config and be sure that your .htaccess isn't rewriting it incorrectly.

Answer (score -5):

Seems the issue ended up being poorly coded templates by previous dev.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what in the code was causing the problem and what the fix was?

Comment: I'm also curious about what was wrong, and an answer like that kind of turns the entire question into something not up to the standards of the site.  Please edit your answer to provide some detail about what the issue turned out to be and how you fixed it.